# IS it impossible to develop a force touch web app without a new apple device?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ios9

I'm currently trying to test Apple force touch events through Safari / Javascript using the iOS 9 simulator.

Normal click events aren't getting registered as force touch events and after reading the general all I could find is that you need a force touch capable device.

Are we really expected to go out and buy new hardware to develop force touch capable devices or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/) at the bottom of the page it says

> With Xcode 7.0 you must develop on a 
>   device that supports 3D Touch. Simulator 
>   in Xcode 7.0 does not support 3D Touch.

Unfortunately it looks like you'll need an actual device that supports 3D Touch in order to develop for it.

Comment: Suggestion: file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting force touch in the simulator.

Comment: I'm hoping they'll resolve this in an upcoming update.